# Update 'stackexchange.com' links in the Tour page, Help Center and other places to HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, help-center, tour-page

Currently there are two links to `http://stackexchange.com` and one link to `http://stackexchange.com/sites` in the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page. They should be changed to `https` of course, because there is a 301 redirect from `http` to `https` anyway.

---

The links in the Help Center should be updated too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

- `http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions`
- `http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve`
- `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/`
- And more...

I haven't gone through all of the articles in the Help Center, so there might be more instances.

---

The link in the Profile page that tells you how good you are links to `http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2017-04-01/754119#754119`:

[image: "How good you are" example]

---

The link to your Network Profile (from your Profile page) links to `http://stackexchange.com/users/392691/alon-eitan`:

[image: Network Profile link example]

---

When asking a question on SO the link **ask it on meta** redirects to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/`

[image: "ask it on meta" link example]

---

When you edit your favorites tags the **advanced tag subscriptions** links to `http://stackexchange.com/filters`:

[image: "advanced tag subscriptions" link example]

---

When voting to close a question as off-topic, the various links all use HTTP, not HTTPS:

[image: Example of various links on Off-topic page]

Comment: Jeff Atwood is finally getting to use his giant S :-)

Comment: @NathanOliver Do you think I should tell him about all the `http` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and probably in the rest of the help center articles? :O

Comment: Sure.  I bet he has been wanting to use it for years ;)

Comment: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't use relative URLs?

Comment: @brandaemon Not always apparently

Comment: Acknowledged. We're getting quite a few of these and working through them as they come up.

Comment: This should be a non-issue by definition. Use relative URLs like we have since the 90s....

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I think protocol-relative URLs are no longer recommended practice in all cases, e.g. see the update at the top of [the blogpost that (I think) started it all](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). (True, if that *had* used protocol-relative URLs this time it wouldn't be an issue, but now that it has to change anyways...)

Comment: Best free hand circle!

Comment: @Jeroen: I don't agree with that site. I can't see how it could possibly be an anti-pattern when all of SO is served via HTTPS. As far as I can tell, using a protocol-relative URI here is a simple example of DRY.

Comment: Now that this question has red circles I can upvote it [:

Comment: @BoundaryImposition See [the detailed reasoning here](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#mistakes-protocol-relative-urls) why they didn't use protocol-relative urls

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The tour page and help center articles will be updated to https with the next build in the hour or so.

The other links you mentioned are going to be deferred for now since they depend on a site-wide helper we're looking into. Not everything is https *just yet* so we're holding off on touching that right this moment.

Comment: Friendly ping: I just edited this question (didn't want to open another one) to include some http links in the vote to close dialog.

Comment: Another friendly ping - In the tour page there is still one link to `http://stackexchange.com` - In the first paragraph (CSS selector: `#mainbar-full > div > div.about-intro > div > div > div > p > a`)